# The split Quaternions are a quotient algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $X$ be an arbitrary set with two elements, say $X = \{x, y \}$. If >$\operatorname{Ass}(X)$ denote the free-associative $\mathbb{F}$-algebra, define $A:= \operatorname{Ass}(X)/I$, where $I$ is the ideal  generated by $x^2+1$, $y^2-1$ and $xy+yx$. Then, $B= \{1, x , y, xy\}$ is a basis for $A.$

1. It's almost obvious that $B$ is linearly independent, but I can't see how to prove it formally. Could you give me an idea?
2. I've able to construct some equivalences classes using $B$, but How can we generate all by linear combinations of elements of $B$?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one way to prove linear independence. There is a representation $\mathrm{Ass}(X)\to\mathbb M_4(\mathbb F)$ given by
$$ x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad y \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$
The generators of $I$ are sent to zero, so it factors through the quotient algebra $A$. The images of $1,x,y,xy$ are linearly independent matrices, so they must already be linearly independent in $A$.

Note that we have just constructed the regular representation.

Comment: If I know correctly, A is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{M}_4(\mathbb{F})$ but $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$

Comment: $A$ is 4-dimensional, so the regular representation gives an algebra homomorphism $A\to\mathbb M_4(\mathbb F)$.

Comment: I'm reading Wikipedia's article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion, and it says that the split quaternions are isomorphic to $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$; do you have a confident source to read about it? By the other side, What do you think about my second question?

Comment: I’m not constructing an algebra isomorphism. Your question asked about showing $1,x,y,xy$ are linearly independent. This I did by constructing an algebra homomorphism where the images are linearly independent.